# Detect Live streaming stopped and resume in nginx

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use Nginx to do live stream to combine two stream into one, so I need to spawn FFMpeg, like so

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://in/1" -i "rtmp://in/2" -filter_complex "overlay=70:50" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -f flv rtmp://out
```

However, is there a way to detect if one of the incoming stream drops, and I can continue the stream? From what I'm reading, it is not possible, and `ffmpeg` task will be killed.